# Why does Appbar overlay not working in Material3 in Android?

Tags: android, material-ui

See this my custom toolbar layout, which was giving elevation automatically:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    style="@style/match_wrap"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/match_wrap"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
        tools:context=".ToolBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_104"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_32"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_vector_logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <com.test.consumer.app.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/offer_name"
                style="@style/wrap_wrap"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:maxLength="40"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                app:customFont="@string/font_raleway_semibold"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/see_offer"/>
            <com.test.consumer.app.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/ctvWishlistIcon"
                style="@style/wrap_wrap"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/see_offer"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_5"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_accent_border"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/action_wishlist"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary_pink"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:customFont="@string/font_raleway_medium" />

            <com.test.consumer.app.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/see_offer"
                style="@style/wrap_wrap"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/textsize_10"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_accent_border"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:text="@string/offers"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary_pink"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:customFont="@string/font_raleway_medium" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_title_bar"
        layout="@layout/layout_titlebar"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

In Material2,

```
<style name="AppThemeV2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Toolbar elevation was coming, but I changed to this, and elevation is not coming:

```
<style name="AppThemeV2" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Please note, there is no change in layout, the only change is, MaterialComponents to material3. I tried to adding some diff diff properties but it is not taking any effect